# Find & Replace functionality automatically formats cells to dates

Tags: vba, excel

Oftentimes when converting PDFs to excel documents, some values are distorted and inaccurate. Precisely, some cells within my "Date" Column do not contain the correct month, grammatically. For example, instead of "`XX Jun`", it is "`XX Iun`", where "XX" represents a day (number).

I've resorted to use the **Find & Replace functionality** and it almost works perfectly, with the only caveat being that, after replacing, my cells are formatted to dates when I want them to remain as texts.

**What I'd therefore like resolved, if possible, is to use the Find & Replace functionality without it formatting my cells to dates after replacing, by modifying my VBA code.**

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select Date Column", "Obtain Range", Type:=8)

rng.Replace What:="ian", Replacement:="Jan"
rng.Replace What:="lan", Replacement:="Jan"
rng.Replace What:="iun", Replacement:="Jun"
rng.Replace What:="lun", Replacement:="Jun"

End Sub
```

For clarity, some screenshots of what happens when I execute my code.

From This:

[image]

To This:

[image]

Comment: `rng.NumberFormat = "@"` before replacing anything

Comment: @TimWilliams I'd assume that it is the same thing as manually formatting my Date column to "Text" and then using the Find & Replace tool. If that is, I've already tried that to no avail.

Comment: Prefix the replacement with a `'`. e.g. `rng.Replace What:="ian", Replacement:="'Jan"`

Comment: @Jeeped Works perfectly with cells that start with the month, followed by the day (Month Day). Not so with cells that have that inverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim rng As Range, v, c

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select Date Column", "Obtain Range", Type:=8)

    'only look at the used range...
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng, rng.Worksheet.UsedRange)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "no cells to fix!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With rng
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        For Each c In .Cells
            v = c.Value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then '<<< ignore empty cells
                v = Replace(v, "ian", "Jan")
                v = Replace(v, "Ian", "Jan")
                v = Replace(v, "iun", "Jun")
                v = Replace(v, "Iun", "Jun")
                c.Value = v
            End If
        Next c
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Really am confused by how excel is tricked into not formatting the cells by simply using 2 more variables... Thanks!

Comment: Crashes in what way?

Comment: Excel becomes irresponsive and I have to end the excel task

Comment: That could happen if you select a huge range (such as a whole column for example)

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried it again and it doesn't crash. However, I have to allow it approx. 20 seconds before it becomes responsive again. Is it because the code is applied to every single cell within the column? If that is, would confining it to a   defined number of rows be better?

Comment: Haha, thats exactly what I did. Thanks for revealing my mistake

Comment: See my edits - that should help in cases where a whole column is selected

Comment: It was not "crashing" before - just running longer than you expected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling Range.Replace, keep your original column, and use another column to call a User Defined Function macro to "fix" the bad OCR value. This function would take in a single argument, the range with the "bad" date, and return a string. Something like this:

```
Public Function FixDate(ByVal s As String) As String
  s = Replace$(s, "ian", "Jan")
  [...other replacements...]
  FixDate = s
End Function
```

Then call it like this:

`=FIXDATE(A2)`

This will have the advantage of keeping your original value in column A for QA/QC, and it won't auto-convert to a date value.

Rather than using the built-in VBA `Replace()` function, you can use the Regular Expression library (requires a reference) to streamline the various replacements, though this may incur a performance hit.

Comment: Other than not knowing what exactly this code does nor how to use it (I'm a beginner), I'm concerned that it'll scan through all "ian"s in my worksheet.