# Change region format to another language with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to **change the region format to "French (Canada)"** in order for `datevalue` to accept french months (eg. 05 Mars, 12 Avril, etc) and then **revert it back to "English (Canada)" within the VBA code**.

I hope it's not as complex and that there is a write property that can **modify this setting with VBA.**

So far, I've found Application.International(xlCountrySetting) but it is only a read property.

This is the setting in question I wish to change:[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro, changing that setting, and then looking at the the recorded macro?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Are macros able to record procedures outside of excel? As far as I know, they can't.

Comment: You cannot do it "directly" with VBA, but you can use VBA to either call a Windows API to do the modification, or you could run a `.reg` file to make the registry changes.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Too bad it isn't possible with VBA. As much as Windows APIs and `.reg`s are interesting, I don't think it would be worth it to learn them just to change the region format: a process that takes 5 seconds when done manually.

Comment: They can't, but I feel like you should be converting those problem values manually so they confirm to the required value, rather than changing the region .... Sorry I thought that was an Excel setting!

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 No problem! I definitely wouldn't mind converting these dates manually... if they weren't as numerous as the stars in the sky. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Sam  The other issue of doing it with VBA code is that Excel won't recognize the change until it is restarted.  And that's pretty messy to do.  Perhaps if you developed a user form for date entry, you could get around that problem.  Or, if your users are entering them in the cells, run a macro to do the translation.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yeah... I don't think I should use VBA for this task. Though your suggestions are thoughtful, your first one (date entry) is rather painful as there are many dates to convert. Your second, though, seems much more feasible. Thanks

Comment: @Sam You could also use a formula on the page to reconstruct the date. No VBA required

Comment: If you're unable to find a solution that is appropriate for your use case, consider writing a custom function (one which works similarly to `datevalue()` but could interpret months' names in French too).

Comment: Didn't mean manually, sorry, I meant create a function that converts the French representation of dates into the format you require... Not manual, but semi automatic!! Eg French format into UTC format, and then into the format you require. Basically you can apply a cell format, and when you set the value, Excel will interpret that value into a standard format. Have you tried installing a French language pack into Excel?

Comment: @chillin Seems like a good idea. Will see if I can write it :)

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I've resorted to just add the replacements I need in the code provided by this fellow: [Find & Replace functionality automatically formats cells to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603904/find-replace-functionality-automatically-formats-cells-to-dates?answertab=votes#tab-top) and then execute my datevalue code. Two steps, but less complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can do this with a couple simple Windows API calls. Instead of assuming that the machine is currently set to "English (Canada)", I'd suggest testing the current setting with `GetUserDefaultLCID`, and then setting it back to that when you're done.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal Locale As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LocaleNameToLCID Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal lpName As LongPtr, dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function LocaleNameToLCID Lib "kernel32" _
       (ByVal lpName As LongPtr, dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Sub Test()
    'Get the locale identifier for French (Canada)
    Dim frCa As Long
    frCa = LocaleNameToLCID(StrPtr("fr-CA"), 0)
    'Make sure there function succeeded.
    If result = 0 Then
        'Cache the current locale
        Dim userLocale As Long
        userLocale = GetUserDefaultLCID
        'Switch to French (Canada)
        If SetThreadLocale(frCa) Then
            'en français
            '...
            'switch back
            SetThreadLocale userLocale
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Documentation links for the relevant functions are below:

- [SetThreadLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale)
- [GetUserDefaultLCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename)
- [LocaleNameToLCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-localenametolcid)

Comment: 0

I could not get the setthreadlocale function to do anything. The localenametolcid does work for seeing what the current settings are. I used this to test the former and it never changes.