# Change regional settings from polish to US windows 10

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to use this code:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal Locale As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LocaleNameToLCID Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal lpName As LongPtr, dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function LocaleNameToLCID Lib "kernel32" _
       (ByVal lpName As LongPtr, dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Sub Test()
    'Get the locale identifier for French (Canada)
    Dim frCa As Long
    frCa = LocaleNameToLCID(StrPtr("fr-CA"), 0)
    'Make sure there function succeeded.
    If result = 0 Then
        'Cache the current locale
        Dim userLocale As Long
        userLocale = GetUserDefaultLCID
        'Switch to French (Canada)
        If SetThreadLocale(frCa) Then
            'en français
            '...
            'switch back
            SetThreadLocale userLocale
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

from link:

[Change region format to another language with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620085/change-region-format-to-another-language-with-vba?fbclid=IwAR2aAkVrSgOEkIZAxBwAYgT_lqB-Kc9JQA6qZAkdP7hySkx34tlnO9W5lNc)

i am looking for similar solution but this above is not working. 
I tried to change regional settings to US settings and bring back to polish regional settings (windows default).

Polish settings from GetUserDefaultLCID = 1045, US = 1033 but macro is running without any results. (no error, no changes). Kind of SetThreadLocale is not working...

Please help what can be wrong,
Best,
Jacek

I tried using instead of "fr-CA" "pl-PL" and assign to userLocale = 1045 when i was using windows with Us regional settings but didnt work.

Goal is to have this macro working in windows 10.

Comment: thank you @Peh, i changed the code for: ` Private Sub Test() Dim userLocale As Long 'US settings number ''from userLocale = GetUserDefaultLCID userLocale = 1033 SetThreadLocale userLocale End Sub ` and nothing is happening after macro is finished, this is working for you? Best, Jacek

Comment: Even after restarting computer this is not working, anyone can help?

Comment: Anyone? please help

Answer (score 1):

Note that `If SetThreadLocale(frCa) Then` switches to `frCa` but 1 line later (after comments) you switch **back** to what is was before with `SetThreadLocale userLocale` (If you read the original thread you linked it tells you exactly this).

So the change is only happening for a short time in between these 2 statements.

So either put your code that should run on the changed locale in between:

```
If SetThreadLocale(frCa) Then
    'put your code that should run in polish here

    SetThreadLocale userLocale
End If
```

or to change the locale permanently use the following instead of the above:

```
SetThreadLocale frCa
```

Comment: @JacekAntek I have no further idea. May I ask why you need to do this? Perhaps there is an alternative solution for your actual issue?

Comment: Hi, thank you. The purpose is to review data from csv file in US settings - it is opening Excel with column formatted file. And go back to polish settings after that. I want to get answer for this code - i want to be a master so i want to know everything inlucding strange code like this one.