# CLng() and CDbl() are dropping decimals

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization, type-conversion

If I run `CLng("22.14")` in my PC's Excel VBA Editor, I get the expected result, `22`. If I do this on *some* international colleagues' PCs, it yields `2214`.

`CDbl` is doing a similar thing. I get `22.14` and they get `2214`.

My thoughts: I hypothesize some setting defines the decimal character (and mine is rightly "." while theirs is something else). My searching didn't yield any other ideas or solutions.

Comment: a) the 'international colleagues' PCs' may be expecting a comma instead of a US-EN decimal point. b) where does `"22.14"` come from? c) are you aware that CLng rounds while Int truncates?

Comment: The obvious solution is not to store numbers in strings. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: I want it to round, so CLng works for me. The data comes from a string of numbers being parsed - it represents column widths being restored from captured user actions in a template. I could change it, but it isn't inefficient (enough) to warrant changing the system - it's worked for years locally.

Comment: All, I may have led us astray as the Application.DecimalSeparator property returns a "." character on the offending PC. So now I am more lost than I was originally.

Answer (score 5):

All of the numeric conversion functions in VBA are locale aware, so they will ignore both thousands separators and currency symbols. The `IsNumeric` function behaves the same way:

```
Public Sub Example()
    'en-US locale
    Debug.Print IsNumeric("$1,1,1,1,1,")    'True
    Debug.Print CLng("$1,1,1,1,1,")         '11111
End Sub
```

The only host agnostic work-around that I'm aware of for dealing with this (other than not storing numbers as `String` data) is to bypass the built in VBA casts entirely and call the underlying [conversion functions in oleaut32.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms885594(v%3dmsdn.10)) directly with a hard-coded locale ID.  For example, to get a `Double` from an en-US localized string:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function VarR8FromStr Lib "oleaut32" _
    (ByVal strIn As LongPtr, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pdblOut As Double) As Long

Public Const EN_US As Long = 1033

Public Function DoubleFromEnUsString(converting As String) As Double
    Dim converted As Double, result As Long
    result = VarR8FromStr(StrPtr(converting), EN_US, 0, converted)
    If (result = 0) Then
        DoubleFromEnUsString = converted
    Else
        Err.Raise 5
    End If
End Function
```

...or a `Long`:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function VarI4FromStr Lib "oleaut32" _
    (ByVal strIn As LongPtr, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef plOut As Long) As Long

Public Const EN_US As Long = 1033

Public Function LongFromEnUsString(converting As String) As Long
    Dim converted As Long, result As Long
    result = VarI4FromStr(StrPtr(converting), EN_US, 0, converted)
    If (result = 0) Then
        LongFromEnUsString = converted
    Else
        Err.Raise 5
    End If
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Public Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print LongFromEnUsString("12.34")     '12
    Debug.Print DoubleFromEnUsString("12.34")   '12.34
End Sub
```

Comment: I _think_ you can just pass in &H7F which is `LOCALE_INVARIANT`, and thus get a locale-independent function. Using the invariant locale seems to work for both input `123.456,789` and `123,456.789`, outputting `123` or `123457`, respectively.

Comment: @this Good point. I saw that, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/locale-invariant) was less than clear as to what "similar to those for English (United States)" means in this context.  The other up-side to using a hard coded locale for a known input format is that it can be more easily modified for non-US formats (and I thought I'd keep the answer more general).

Comment: I am thinking through this as I type, but one challenge is that the string can originate from either locale depending on who saved the project last. Now I need to find out if their system settings really are different and whether it impacts the string that gets saved to be parsed later by any user. If the answers are Yes and No, then I _think_ @Comintern 's answer will work perfectly.

Comment: @Corey You can always use the `GetUserDefaultLCID` API function (VBA declarations and links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624205/4088852)) to determine the system settings. The potential problem is that if a, say, de-DU user saves a number as a local string and it's later opened by an en-US machine you can't determine that by simply the locale setting.  If *your code* is saving these as string, you can fix that by saving them as numbers and using the locale for formatting (thus the comment on the question about where the data is originating).

Comment: The other option would be saving them as locale invariant strings and using the conversion method noted in the comment @this made above.

Comment: Gah! The results are in, the first answer is No. See my comment in the original post.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what @this was getting at.

Comment: @Corey I'm missing something then. Your question is about ***reading*** a string encoded number that assumes a specific regional setting.  Your comment makes it sound like the problem is on the ***output*** side. Which is it?  If it's output (saving the number as an invariant string) that's a completely different question, although there are also oleaut functions to do that (see the link in the answer).

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for your patience. The initial question was indeed on reading. But in finding that reading was an issue, I am now looking ahead at possible issues with writing (perhaps confusing the issue). For now, my original question stands but with one more data point: Their PC returns "." when they call Application.DecimalSeparator.

Comment: @Corey The return value of `Application.DecimalSeparator` makes no difference at all - only the encoding of the source string. That's the reason this was posted as an alternative answer to the one that is actually using it. The code above will ***always*** use en-US regional settings for the conversion, regardless of the locale of the machine it's run on.

Comment: Unfortunately, Comintern's suggestion appears to not solve the issue. LongFromEnUsString still returns `2214` for the offending PCs. So, I'm still at a loss.

Answer (score 3):

The two most common decimal separators are `"."` (US, UK...) and `","` (Italy, France...).
You can easily access this property from VBA using `Application.DecimalSeparator` (returning the OS' separator).

The **right** solution would be not to have `"22.14"` be treated as a `String` but as a real number, so that this kind of internationalization issue is let to the operating system.

If you *really* cannot have this number differently than a `String` (for example, you're getting these values from an English/American API which sends you the deserialized numbers), then you may use a similar function:

```
Function InternationalCLng(ByVal st As String)

    Dim EnglishSep As Boolean: EnglishSep = ("." = Application.DecimalSeparator)
    If Not EnglishSep Then
        st = Replace(st, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)
    End If
    InternationalCLng = CLng(st)

End Function
```

... which replaces the `.` with the right `DecimalSeparator` and use `InternationalCLng("22.14")` instead.
But honestly, this is a hack.

Comment: The decimal separator isn't the only problem - the thousands separator gets ignored (as does any leading currency symbol).  I.e. `CLng("$1,1,1.1,1,")` is perfectly "legit".

Comment: @Comintern the `$` symbol could also be trailing ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Makes sense - leading or trailing is also culture specific.