# Can't get rid of "old format or invalid type library" error in vba

Tags: vba, vb.net, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba to get some set names from a webpage and the script is getting them accordingly until it catches an error somewhere within the execution. This is the first time I encountered such error.

> What my script is doing is get all the links under `Company Sets` and then tracking down each of the links it goes one layer deep and then following all the links under `Set Name` it goes another layer deep and finally parse the table from there. I parsed the name of `PUBLISHED SET` which is stored within the variable `bName` instead of the table as the script is getting bigger. I used IE to get the `PUBLISHED SET` as there are few leads which were causing encoding issues.

I searched through all the places to find any workaround but no luck.

However, I came across ***[this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?582894-vb-2008-excel-automation-error-Old-format-or-invalid-type-library)*** where there is a proposed solution written in vb but can't figure out how can I make it work within vba.

Script I'm trying with:

```
Sub FetchRecords()
    Const baseUrl$ = "https://www.psacard.com"
    Const link = "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Htmldoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, bName$, tRow As Object
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object, posts As Object, I&, R&, C&
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim idic As Object: Set idic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set posts = Html.querySelectorAll(".dataTable tr td a[href*='/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/']")
    For I = 0 To posts.Length - 7
        idic(baseUrl & Split(posts(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)) = 1
    Next I

    For Each key In idic.Keys
        With Http
            .Open "GET", key, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If InStr(post.getAttribute("title"), "Contact User") > 0 Then
                If InStr(post.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href"), "publishedset") > 0 Then
                    IE.Visible = True
                    IE.navigate baseUrl & Split(post.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)
                    While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                    Set Htmldoc = IE.document
                    bName = Htmldoc.querySelector("h1 b.text-primary").innerText
                    If InStr(bName, "/") > 0 Then bName = Split(Htmldoc.querySelector(".inline-block a[href*='/contactuser/']").innerText, " ")(1)
                    R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = bName
                End If
            End If
        Next post
    Next key
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

I get that error pointing at the following line after extracting records between 70 to 90:

```
bName = Htmldoc.querySelector("h1 b.text-primary").innerText
```

The error looks like:

```
Automation Error: old format or invalid type library
```

Proposed solution in the linked thread written in vb (can't convert to vba):

```
'save the current settings for easier restoration later
Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = _
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

'change the settings
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

Your code here

'restore the previous settings
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
```

Comment: [This support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320369/bug-old-format-or-invalid-type-library-error-when-automating-excel) suggests that a second workaround is to "Install the Multilingual User Interface Pack for your version of Office". You can *try* using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624205/4088852) using API calls, but I can't guarantee it will be suitable for this purpose (or that the locale is really at fault here).

Comment: I am able to produce the issue when I try to test the above code. https://i.postimg.cc/FHn8bZXg/71.png As suggested in the Official documentation that it is bug in Office. so you can try to install that Multilingual pack and let us know about your testing result. If issue persist than try to inform us which exact OS version, Office version and IE version you are using currently. We will try to make further tests to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I have installed that Multilingual pack and ran the script again but that didn't solve the problem. I'm still having the same error `Automation Error: old format or invalid type library` @Deepak-MSFT .

Comment: you can have a + from me. However, what settings do you have as I cannot reproduce this, I assume because of my current settings.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr. I'm using win 7 ultimate and office 2013 professional plus. I went through both of their language setting and they are set to english.

Comment: I'll try running again tonight. It had got to 100 and still was running when I tried this morning with English settings.

Comment: I get that error in between 70 to 80.