# Excel VBA can not open workbook with special caracter in file path

Tags: excel, vba

We recently startad to upgrade our PC-s from Win 7 to Win 10. The problem occured on win 10 system.

I have an excel code that opens a workbook to copy from it. But the file path contains hungarian characters, therefore on the win 10 system the macro could not find the source file.

We found out that the Windows regional settings has a Unicode UTF-8 option which solves the problem, however we have a plenty of custom made hardvare programming scripts which could not work with this option, so we can not change it on the system globally.

Is there a way to open the file with another character coding in the file path, than the system default? Is it possible to change the settings at the start of the macro and change back at the end of it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620085/change-region-format-to-another-language-with-vba